# call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Google\Client' does not have a method 'getVideoInfo'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, youtube-api

I'm working with the Alaout and Dawson package, when I get the information, I get this error.
I have tried to shorten the Facades but I still can't figure it out.
Here is the controller with the function

```
class VideoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $videos = Youtube::getVideoInfo('YbIkHQVpDJ8');
        return view('content.videoindex', compact('videos'));
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
```

Comment: Exactly which dependencies you are using and what package you are trying to run the YouTube class from?